# Subtract time in 24 hour format using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, time, momentjs

I have a start and end time in the format of HH:MM and I need to get the total time in hours. I have tried a couple methods like trimming the string to an hour and minutes then multiplying the hours by 60 and adding the minutes but since the minute string is two digits, 00 I get an answer that is a power of ten greater than what I need. I also feel like this approach is inefficient.

So what is the best way to subtract 04:30 and 22:00? I also have access to moment.js if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [moment.js' difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
var a = moment('22:00', 'HH:mm');
var b = moment('04:30', 'HH:mm');
a.diff(b, 'hours', true)
```

Comment: Very nice, I have one small edit to show the minutes as a decimal. Thank you!

Comment: Great! @GarrettFogerlie